# Apply function to dataframe column based on combinations of values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, scipy

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Region | Country | Product | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2016 | 500 |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2017 | 400 |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2018 | 15 |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2019 | 450 |
| Africa | Uganda | ABC | 2016 | 750 |
| Africa | Uganda | ABC | 2017 | 670 |
| Africa | Uganda | ABC | 2018 | 1300 |
| Africa | Uganda | ABC | 2019 | 890 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2016 | 500 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2017 | 420 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2018 | 415 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2019 | 0 |

```
data = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
         'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','Uganda','Uganda','Uganda','Uganda','Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan'],
         'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','DEF','DEF','DEF','DEF'],
         'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
         'Price': [500, 400, 15,450,750,670,1300,890,500,420,415,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to calculate the Interquartile Range to identify outliers and extract the index positions of potential outliers.

I created a function however, I am having trouble applying the function to the `Price` column based on combinations of the `Region` and `Product` columns.

My function is below:

```
def tukeys_method(df, variable, iterable1, iterable2):
    itr1 = df[iterable1].unique() #create list of unique values for iterable 1
    itr2 = df[iterable2].unique() #create list of unique values for iterable 2
    for (i,j) in zip(itr1, itr2):
        
        #Takes two parameters: dataframe & variable of interest as string
        q1 = df.groupby([iterable1,iterable2])[variable].quantile(0.25) #calculate quantiles
        q3 = df.groupby([iterable1,iterable2])[variable].quantile(0.75) #calculate quantiles
        iqr = q3-q1
        inner_fence = 1.5*iqr
        outer_fence = 3*iqr
    
        #inner fence lower and upper end
        inner_fence_le = q1-inner_fence
        inner_fence_ue = q3+inner_fence
    
        #outer fence lower and upper end
        outer_fence_le = q1-outer_fence
        outer_fence_ue = q3+outer_fence
    
        outliers_prob = []
        outliers_poss = []
        for index, x in enumerate(df.groupby([iterable1,iterable2])[variable]):
            if x <= outer_fence_le or x >= outer_fence_ue:
                outliers_prob.append(index)
        for index, x in enumerate(df.groupby([iterable1,iterable2])[variable]):
            if x <= inner_fence_le or x >= inner_fence_ue:
                outliers_poss.append(index)
        return outliers_prob, outliers_poss
        


probable_outliers_tm, possible_outliers_tm = tukeys_method(df, "Price",'Region','Product')
```

I get the following error when I run the function:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (570,) (2,)
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, if anyone is interested, the solution is below:

```
# Identify outliers using Tukey's method.
def outliers_tukey(df, variable, iterable1, iterable2):
    outliers_prob = []
    outliers_poss = []
    for (i,j) in itertools.product(df[iterable1].unique(), df[iterable2].unique()):
        
        #Takes two parameters: dataframe & variable of interest as string
        q1 = df.loc[(df[iterable1]==i) & (df[iterable2]==j)][variable].quantile(0.25)
        q3 = df.loc[(df[iterable1]==i) & (df[iterable2]==j)][variable].quantile(0.75)
        iqr = q3-q1
        inner_fence = 1.5*iqr
        outer_fence = 3*iqr
    
        #inner fence lower and upper end
        inner_fence_le = q1-inner_fence
        inner_fence_ue = q3+inner_fence
    
        #outer fence lower and upper end
        outer_fence_le = q1-outer_fence
        outer_fence_ue = q3+outer_fence
    

        for index, x in enumerate(df[variable]):
            if x <= outer_fence_le or x >= outer_fence_ue:
                outliers_prob.append(index)
        for index, x in enumerate(df[variable]):
            if x <= inner_fence_le or x >= inner_fence_ue:
                outliers_poss.append(index)
        return outliers_prob, outliers_poss
        

probable_outliers_tm, possible_outliers_tm = outliers_tukey(df, "Price",'Region','Product')
```